# Using a Django generated slug URL to link to specific pages

Tags: python, django, slug

Hi generous and kind people of Stack Overflow. I'm fairly new to Python and Django, and have undertaken the project of building a portfolio for my copywriting.

I have a main landing page that's going to have a grid of 9 different writing projects. Someone will click on one of the images for a project and then be brought over to a new page that has a more detailed description of the project.

Each individual project page has a URL, whose path contains a slug. The code I have works in generating this path. Each writing project will have a URL path that contains projects/(slug)

My problem is that I can't get this slug based link that will point to each individual page to work in my code. I'm getting this error: NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'individual_project' not found. 'individual_project' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Please forgive any wonkiness with this code, as I am struggling a bit in understanding it all.

Here is my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, get_list_or_404
from .models import Project

def individual_project_view(request, project_id):
     projectpage = get_list_or_404(Project, slug=project_id) 
     return render(request, 'projects/project_detail.html', {'projectpage':projectpage})

def project_home(request):
     portfolioprojects = get_list_or_404(Project)
     return render(request, 'projects/project_detail.html', {'portfolioprojects':portfolioprojects})
```

Here is my urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from projects import views
app_name = 'portfolio'

urlpatterns = [path('<slug:project_id>', views.individual_project_view, name='individual_project'),]
```

And finally my HTML:

```
<a href="{% url 'individual_project' %}">
<img src="{{ project.image.url }}" class="img-fluid mb-2"></a>
{% endif %}
<div>
<h2 class= "category">{{ project.category }}</h2>
<h3 class="client">{{ project.description }}</h3>
<h4 class="project_type">{{ project.title }}</h4>
</div>
```

Thanks for reading - and I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an expression for the slug in your [**`{% url … %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url):

```
<a href="{% url 'portfolio:individual_project' project.slug %}">
```

Since you defined an `app_name` in the `urls.py`, you need to prefix it with the `app_name`, so `portfolio:individual_project` instead of <s>`individual_project`</s>.

Comment: @JeffCardello: do you have a "root" `urls.py`?

Comment: @JeffCardello: what if you import this with: `path('projects/', include('projects.urls', name='portfolio')`?

Comment: Hi Willem. I used this path in my root urls.py. I'm now getting this error - it seems like the actual slug isn't getting included when I reference the URL. The error I'm getting is:

NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'individual_project' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['projects/(?P<project_id>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']

Do you have an idea of what else I may need to check?

Comment: @JeffCardello: it means `project` does not exists where you wrote the `{% url ... %}`. You can only work with `project.pk` given that you are in the *scope* where the `project` exists.

Comment: Okay - that makes sense, and when I change it to project.pk I do get links that end with a unique integer when I hover over each project. It was cool to see this happen. I've seen a couple posts referring to get_absolute_url. Would this be a better way to things?

thanks again!

Comment: @JeffCardeilo: if there is a canonical page for each item individually, then yes, using `get_absolute_url` is better, but of course you can only define *one* per model object.

Comment: Right now, each individual detail page for each piece in the portfolio is generated from a single template - project_detail.html, which gets populated by the info I fill into the fields in admin, and reference on project_detail.html. Currently all of my individual portfolio pages display perfectly, and each has its own individual URL that, like http://127.0.0.1:8000/projects/webflow, http://127.0.0.1:8000/projects/petsmart, etc. So since each does not have its own individual html page, being generated from a single template, it wouldn't be canonical? Thanks again for your time and patience!

Answer (score 0):

To correctly reverse path by name you should provide not only the name but also arguments if they defined for this path. So the correct way to use {% url %} in this case would be

```
<a href="{% url 'individual_project' project.slug %}">
```

Comment: Thanks for you help Alexey, I do appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

```
<a href="{% url 'individual_project' project.slug %}">
```

or you use "reverse" method by django. in your class model:

```
from django.urls import reverse

# this method called automaticallly by django. we are manuallly calling it here
  def get_absolute_url(self):
    # u create url only here and then reference here throughout of your project
    return reverse("individual_project",args=[self.slug])
```

in your template:

```
 # looks like instance_of_model is project.
 # we are not hardcoding the url, passing a reference
  <a href="{{project.get_absolute_url}}">   </a>
```

Comment: This is getting me close!

Here's the problem. I have two apps. I have one for the main landing page named Portfolio that has its own models.py. This has fields for the portfolio image, and text fields. This fills in the information in my home.html template.

I have a second app named Project for the project detail pages. It has its own associated models. This has all the lengthier info about the project, as well as the slug. Your solution produced the right links here. But not needed on it.

I need to get the class in Projects w/ slug into views for Portfolio. Thanks for your help!